# HTML Textarea: Why does textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px" expand the textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I know that the following code will expand the `textarea` every time a key is pressed within the textarea.

However, why does this work? Why does it expand the textarea when I am just setting the element's height equal to the scrollHeight? I'm not incrementing the scrollHeight, or at least not intentionally?

```js
const expandTextArea = (element) => {
  element.target.style.height = element.target.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area" onkeyup="expandTextArea(event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: It works because the scrollheight is the full height of the content within the textarea. For example, the content within the textarea may be 500px tall, while the height of the textarea is 100px. Under normal circumstances, the lower 400px of the content would be cut off, causing the user to scroll. Setting the full height of the element to be the full 500px removes the scrollbar and shows all content.

Comment: `I'm not incrementing the scrollHeight, or at least not intentionally?` The scrollHeight wil update itself every time the content of the textarea is changed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is there a reason then, why the textarea still grows even when I delete text from the box (which you would think would cause the box to shrink)?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The issue appears to be that setting `style.height` of the textarea element to the element's `scrollHeight` increases the `scrollHeight` attribute value in the process (by 4px in my testing).  The concern is where does the extra scrollHeight come from, and how to prevent the rendered height increasing if the text is not overflowing the textarea's content box.

Answer (score 1):

What a great question! Some experimentation showed that

- Textarea elements are widgets used by a native code editor to show edited text and don't always reflect the DOM attributes that you might expect from, say, an inline-block element.
- The `scrollHeight` attribute of a text area element does not reflect the pixel height of text content of the element - it shows the height of the screen area representing the underlying native code editor's view port window.
- Setting CSS property `overflow-y` to `visible` had no effect on text area presentation:- adding additional lines to text area content produced a vertical scrollbar, not content extending outside the element's content box.

Console logs during investigation suggested the following solution:

```js
const expandTextArea = (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if( target.scrollHeight > target.clientHeight) {
      target.style.height = target.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}

const detailTextArea = (event) => {
   const rect = area.getBoundingClientRect();
   const styleHeight = area.styleHeight;
   console.log( "#area style.height: %s, clientHeight: %s, scrollHeight: %s, rect.height: %s",
       area.style.Height, area.clientHeight, area.scrollHeight, rect.height);
};
```

```html
<textarea id="area" rows="3" oninput="expandTextArea(event)"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick = "detailTextArea()">Log Details</button>
```

---

**MDN**

Looking up MDN afterwards found an [auto growing text area example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#autogrowing_textarea_example) that is functionally equivalent. Minor differences include

1. Setting a `rows` attribute on the `<textarea>` to an integer number of rows cleaned up the values seen on the console considerably.

   - The values of `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` were never the same without the `rows` attribute (in Firefox).
2. CSS `overflow` properties were not seen to be required (and may be different to what you expect).

**Reducing textarea size?**

Reducing textarea size when the number of content lines goes down is problematic: the minimum value of `scrollOffset` is the textarea's `clientHeight` value which does not respond to the height of rendered text being lower. Simplistically leaving it to users to resize the text area is the easiest way out.